# The shortest way to find out if the collection of elements is visible in Selenide

Tags: selenide

I was wondering if anyone knew a short and beautiful way to get a boolean value of elements collection visibility.

I mean, if I have an ElementsCollection object, what should I do to understand if it's visible or not, and save the result to a boolean variable.

Please, note, that I use Selenide, not bare Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many ways you can do this.  One way is to return another ElementsCollection that will only contain either elements that are visible or not visible (based on which Condition you choose).  Such as:

```
ElementsCollection stuffThatMayBeVisible;
return stuffThatMayBeVisible.filterBy(Condition.visible);
```

This will let you now work with an ElementsCollection that you know contains only visible/hidden SelenideElements.

Another method which is more aligned with answering your actual question is so use a `for` loop and go through each SelenideElement and check using `.isDisplayed()` which returns a Boolean.  I'd recommend not using this method though, the first example I gave is far cleaner.

```
ElementsCollection stuffThatMayBeVisible;
List<Boolean> boolList; // what a great variable name

for (SelenideElement element : stuffThatMayBeVisible) {
  boolList.add(element.isDisplayed());
}
return boolList;
```

Comment: The first one seems beautiful enough to me. Will try, thank you!